# How do I assign a value to a word?

Tags: string, key-value-store

I'm creating a calculating list for the user to select from such as: pepsi, sprite, coke
and after user selects their fav drink, it will calculate: the calories(they all have diff. calories) + plus how many they drink per week + per year and then Print how many total calories they consume per year.

I got the math part down but I can't figure out how to add the "drink" they select into the final output.

```
EXAMPLE:
pepsi 100 
sprite 200
coke 300
```

So, if they select pepsi, it should then take variable pepsi, then add how many per day + week + year then print total calories for year. Make sense?

right now it just prints the same number for any selection. when clearly the calories will vary.

Here is how I tried coding it:

```
cans_per_day = int(input("\nHow many cans per day?\n"))

sodas_per_week = int(input("How many cans do you drink per week?\n"))


drink_of_choice = input("What's your drink of choice?\n\n" + "Pepsi\nWild Cherry Coke\nOrange Fanta\nMountain Dew\nMello Yello\nSprite\n\n")


    
drink_of_choice = input + 41 * cans_per_day * sodas_per_week * 4 * 12 / (453.592)

print(drink_of_choice)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post is missing a lot of info. What language are you using? Where is your code? Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using python. Above, I put the problem code that I was struggling with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just check which drink is selected with something like this (if you use python):

```
if drink == "pepsi":
    calories = 100
elif drink == "sprite":
    calories = 200
elif drink == "coke":
   calories = 300
```

then you can just multiply with `calories` in your calculation

Comment: Thank you!!. I'll give this a go. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond and add the code :)